# Add ComboBox field in GridView control, Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, x++

I want to add ComboBox type control in GridView, how is it possible just like that?
[image]

Comment: Could you give us some more context, table name etc. Do you need a field bound to a table field, do need an enum or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add an enum control to the grid control (not GridView). Also adding a string field with relation to a table (a foreign key) will give a lookup which is similar to combobox.

A good starting point is reading about [form controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg840964.aspx).